# deleted files remains open consuming huge disk space

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, diskspace

I am running java processes.But that consumes huge amount of disk space keeping some deleted files opened. The location of the files is /tmp (i.e. while i am not exclusively creating those files). What can be the reason for such occurrences and how to overcome it?

Comment: how exactly do you delete the files?

Comment: how to open deleted files?

Comment: @Sorontur ..i dont delete the files .. i jus came to know about case and want to solve the issue

Comment: How do you know then that they are deleted :)

Comment: lsof -s | grep deleted | sort -k 8

Comment: In UNIX and Linux and friends, deleted files remain until they are finally closed. If that doesn't answer your question it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP...i came to know that..but how to close those files?? ..that is what i am asking..i am not creating those files exclusively

Comment: You 'came to know it' because somebody told you, possibly me. Until you post the code concerned it's impossible for anyone to know what you're talking about, let alone help you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se]. Or actually you should search for the question there, because it's a pretty common question and it's likely to already have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen for instance on Linux when a process is still using a file while another process deletes that file. The file will appear as deleted, but under the hood, the kernel will not free up the space as long as any process is still using the file descriptor.

To release the space, you have to tell the program to close the file descriptor. This depends entirely on the program design and might not even be possible. For example, if this was a word processor, you would choose File->Close in main menu.

If you are unable to "tell" the program to close the file, your final option is to terminate the process.

If you like playing around, you can also attach to process with a debugger such as `gdb`, find the descriptor and close it manually. Note that this might cause the program to crash or behave unexpectedly.

In all cases where the file is abruptly closed, its contents will likely be corrupted.

I don't think this can happen on Windows because Windows uses different locking semantics and will not allow a file to be deleted if it's open.